# mounting a path override the existing content

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am facing issues when mounting a path.My objective is to make the data persistent even when the pod restarts.But its creating a new directory which doesnt have any of my config files. How to mount a entire directory without overriding it? I should have all my database data inside the path eventhough the pod restarts.In my scenario,its creating a new path.

my dockerfile

```
FROM centos:7
ENV DIR /binaries
ENV PASS admin
WORKDIR ${DIR}
COPY libstdc++-4.8.5-39.el7.x86_64.rpm ${DIR} 
COPY numactl-libs-2.0.12-3.el7.x86_64.rpm ${DIR}
COPY mysqlmonitor-8.0.18.1217-linux-x86_64-installer.bin ${DIR}
RUN yum install -y libaio && yum -y install gcc && yum -y install gcc-c++ && yum -y install compat-libstdc++-33 && yum -y install libstdc++-devel && yum -y install elfutils-libelf-devel && yum -y install glibc-devel && yum -y install libaio-devel && yum -y install sysstat
RUN yum install -y gcc && yum install -y make && yum install -y apr-devel && yum install -y openssl-devel && yum install -y java
RUN rpm -ivh numactl-libs-2.0.12-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
RUN useradd sql
RUN chown sql ${DIR}
RUN chmod 777 ${DIR}
RUN chmod 755 /home/sql
USER sql
WORKDIR ${DIR}
RUN ./mysqlmonitor-8.0.18.1217-linux-x86_64-installer.bin --installdir /home/sql/mysql/enterprise/monitor --mode unattended --tomcatport 18080 --tomcatsslport 18443 --adminpassword ### --dbport 13306
RUN rm -rf /binaries/*
VOLUME /home/mysql/mysql/enterprise/monitor/mysql/data
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/home/sql/mysql/enterprise/monitor/mysqlmonitorctl.sh start && tail -f /home/sql/mysql/enterprise/monitor/apache-tomcat/logs/mysql-monitor.log"]
```

my deployment file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mypod
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mem     
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mem
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mem
        image: 22071997/mem
        command: 
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /home/sql/mysql/enterprise/mysql/data
          name: volume
      volumes:
      - name: volume
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mem-pvc2
```

output:

```
[sql@mypod-67cb4f85b8-9km26 data]$ pwd
/home/sql/mysql/enterprise/mysql/data
[sql@mypod-67cb4f85b8-9km26 data]$ ls
[sql@mypod-67cb4f85b8-9km26 data]$
```

Comment: Mounting something over a path (both in standard Linux and in Kubernetes) always hides what was there previously.

Answer (score 0):

By default when you mount some volume over a existent path, the content of this existent path will be **hidded**.

If you want to keep both there is an option called `subPath`, in this way you are able to mount each file individually using the same volume:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: echo
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: echo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: echo
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: task-pv-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: task-pv-claim
      containers:
      - name: echo
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
          - name: task-pv-storage
            mountPath: "/usr/share/nginx/html/index.htm"
            subPath: "index.htm"
          - name: task-pv-storage
            mountPath: "/usr/share/nginx/html/teste.html"
            subPath: "teste.html"
```

In this example I have only one volume called **task-pv-storage**, is a `hostPath` volume and in the folder there are only 2 files: `teste.yaml` and `index.html`, and when I apply this config, both files will be placed beside the original files in the container:

```
$ kubectl exec echo-5955898b58-gvgh9 -- ls /usr/share/nginx/html
50x.html  index.htm  index.html  teste.html
```

As you can see it is possible, but will cost an addional configuration, maybe you could keep all file only in the volume instead directly in the container.

**References**

[Configure volume storage/](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-volume-storage/)

[Multiple kubernetes volumes directory](https://blog.sebastian-daschner.com/entries/multiple-kubernetes-volumes-directory)